# When to update IndexedDB data in a Blazor WebAssembly Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, indexeddb

I have a Blazor WebAssembly (PWA) project with a separate ASP.NET api which is used to access product data stored in a database. Calling the `/api/products/getAllProducts` endpoint takes a few seconds because there are quite a number of products that need to get returned. This product data gets updated on the server once a day by a service.

The product data needs to be stored for offline usage for the client, so I am in the process of implementing IndexedDB to use for the local products storage. This code is somewhat untested since its all just sitting in the code block for the products page at the moment:

```
private IEnumerable<Product>? products;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    // get products from the api
    products = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Product[]>("/api/products/GetAllProducts");


    // add products fetched from api into local storage
    using var db = await DbFactory.Create<IndexDb>();
    db.allProducts.Clear();
    foreach ( var product in products)
    {
        db.allProducts.Add(product);
    }
    await db.SaveChanges();


    // get products from local storage
    products = db.allProducts;
}
```

My question is, when should I refresh/repopulate my local IndexedDB product list from the api call without slowing/stopping my application? On startup of the blazor app (is that even possible)? When they open the page that contains all the products? Realistically I only need to update this product data once a day when they first open it that day.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement this in MainLayout.razor

```
@update()

@code{
    public async Task update()
    {
        using var db = await DbFactory.Create<IndexDb>();
        var lastUpdateTime = db.lastUpdateTime.Last();
        if (lastUpdateTime.date < DateTime.Now.date)
        {
            db.allProducts.Clear();
            foreach (var product in products)
            {
                db.allProducts.Add(product);
            }

            db.lastUpdateTime.Add(DateTime.Now);
            await db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```